# How to Disable Hardware SPI Chip Enable/Chip Select?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, spi, adafruit

I'm setting up a Raspberry Pi 4b with a number of Adafruit chips, and thus have used their CircuitPython library to control SPI communication. They've conveniently set up a way to use any GPIO pins as chip selects, but as a result I had no idea that there are two hardware chip selects on the Raspi (CE0 and CE1 on GPIO8 and GPIO7 respectively). I have already wired these pins (GPIO7&8) with the intention of using them as GPIO outputs, but I've noticed I GPIO8/CE0 is connected to the SPI clock.

Adafruit actually mentions that the NO_CS flag doesn't work in their documentation, and I can't seem to find anything useful online.

How can I disable the hardware CS pins? I know the SPI_NO_CS flag in SPI_MODE is already a bug in the spi-bcm library, and I found this patch, but I'm not sure if it would work (I think CircuitPython utilizes a hardware CS?), let alone how to apply it

Comment: read the overlay docs in `/boot/overlays/README` - depending on which overlay you are using (you haven't specified what "a number of Adafruit chips" is), you can usually set which pin to use as CS - or, even simpler, use GPIOs other than 7 and 8 for whatever it is you are using them for

Comment: `GPIO8/CE0 is connected to the SPI clock.` huh? GPIO11 is SPI clock

Comment: Ah let me see.  (1) CE0 should not be connected to SPI clock. They are different pins. (2) If you don't want to use the on board hardware CS pins, eg CS0 of SPI 0, 0, or CS1 of SPI 0, 1. Then you just do not hardware connect the corresponding pin to the CS chip of the SPI (eg. sensor) device/chip/module. In stead you use you own software to use any other GPIO to fake the new CS pin. I read that Rpi4B is not compatible to Circuit Python, and there are guys doing a workaround with MicroPython.

Comment: @JaromandaX we're just using MAX318566's, but we've used all of the pins on the entire pi and were hoping to not rewire it (but rather disable the hardware CS). Also, I realized this was a problem because an ohmmeter measured no resistance between GPIO8 and SCLK, no idea how it works internally though

Comment: @tlfong01 (1) It might have been a problem with the ohmmeter that I used, but there is definitely low resistance between CE0 and SCLK, not constantly though. (2) My question was about how to disable CE0, I am aware I could just not use those pins. (3) Rpi4b is definitely compatible with CircuitPython, and as far as I'm aware CircuitPython  and MicroPython can't disable hardware CS.

Comment: @JaromandaX also we're only using software chip selects, so we don't need to use CE0 at all